# How would I find the cygwin version which has been installed on my machine

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, windows-vista

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) - How would I find the Cygwin's version which has been installed on my machine? (Windows Vista)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With the `uname` utility, as on other POSIX systems.

```
uname -r
```

Comment: Or check the version information of cygwin1.dll using Windows Explorer.

Comment: @BCran this is more general. I want to know what version of Cygwin had been installed on a failed hard drive from which files were restored. I don't want to execute any files there.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to detect if you're running the 32 bit or 64 bit version, the -m switch will tell you:

`uname -m`

"i686" for the 32-bit version, "x86_64" if it's 64-bit.

`uname -a`

..gives you all the information at once. Check `man uname` for details.

(This is also answered in [How do I tell whether my cygwin installation is 32 or 64 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687184/how-do-i-tell-whether-my-cygwin-installation-is-32-or-64-bit))