# How do I tell whether my cygwin installation is 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: cygwin

How do I tell whether my cygwin installation is 32 or 64 bit?
I don't remember which setup.exe to download. And I would hate to mess up my cygwin installation.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`uname -m`

And it should say `x86_64` in the output if it's 64-bit, or `i686` if 32-bit.

Answer (score 23):

Run `uname -m`. If your cygwin install is 64-bit, the output will be `x86_64`. If it's 32-bit, you will instead see `i386`, `i486`, `i586`, or `i686`.

Answer (score 10):

The other answers address the OP's question, but if you're like me and use both flavors of Cygwin, it's useful to know which one you're using for more than just running setup.exe. If I know my script is running on Cygwin, I prefer

```
uname -m
```

because it gives me only "x86_64" or "i686" as output. I can use that in an "if" block like this:

```
if [ $(uname -m) == "x86_64" ]; then do something; fi
```

Of course, you can also use "uname -a" with "grep" in an if statement. It's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

NateT gives the correct command to "print the machine hardware name" according to "uname --help":

```
uname -m
```

I get "x86_64" or "i686", but who knows whether those strings will change? Here's the entire output of "uname -a". The WOW64 tells you it's 32-bit Cygwin on 64-bit Windows. On 32-bit you've got no choice, right? ; - )

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 Pegasus 1.7.32(0.274/5/3) 2014-08-13 23:03 i686 Cygwin
```

**Update:** (Thanks to theDrake.) Ironically, since around Feb 2015 [the WOW64 in the string has changed to WOW](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-02/msg00938.html), so although checking for WOW is probably safe now it seems the "machine hardware name" might indeed be safer than the "kernel name".

Cygwin does seem to be take backwards compatibility seriously according to that thread, but also note that under MSYS2 you'd need to rely on the "machine hardware name" anyway and not the "kernel name":

```
$ uname -a
MSYS_NT-6.1 Pegasus 2.5.0(0.295/5/3) 2016-03-15 11:29 x86_64 Msys
```

Comment: With my current setup, 32-bit Cygwin in a 64-bit Windows 10 environment, running `uname -a` shows `CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW` without the "64" (the output ends with `i686 Cygwin`, just as in your example). So, perhaps your interpretation is not quite correct? I wonder where this discrepancy's coming from.

Comment: Hah, I didn't expect the WOW64 string to change, but here's why they did it: https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-02/msg00938.html

Comment: Thanks for finding that! Pity they had to make such a potentially confusing change.

Comment: Yeah, it shows up the "kernel" name as being pretty arbitrary. Then again, I notice above you listed quite a few values for "machine hardware name", and I suspect one day ARM (32, 64) etc will be added to the list.