# How to get Cygwin DLL version before installation (command line output)?

Tags: cygwin

Periodically downloaded [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)'s `setup.exe` installs newer version of Cygwin DLL.

The installer GUI shows the version, but I want to get it using command line in the output, for example:

```
setup.exe --something-like-version
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506287/how-would-i-find-the-cygwin-version-which-has-been-installed-on-my-machine) shows how to get this after installation, but it's too late for me.

Comment: Do you mean before installing cygwin from scratch or before an update ? What matter in the first case ?

Comment: @matzeri, I mean before installation from scratch. However, even it it is an update, the version should still come from the (yet uninstalled) package. I'm not sure what is the approach. But I guess that it (fresh installation or update) should not really matter because if I can retrieve version of the software content before updating, I should likely be able to use similar way to get the same value before installing from scratch. The source of value (the version) comes from the same place - yet uninstalled downloaded software files.

Comment: looks on https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/cygwin/

Comment: @matzeri, post this version of the answer (can be new or update old), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cygcheck -p cygwin1.dll |grep "cygwin:"
cygwin-2.5.1-1 - cygwin: The UNIX emulation engine (installed binaries and support files)
cygwin-2.5.2-1 - cygwin: The UNIX emulation engine (installed binaries and support files)
cygwin-2.6.0-0.5 - cygwin: The UNIX emulation engine (installed binaries and support files)
```

the last line is a test version (release 0.5). 
So `cygwin-2.5.2-1` is the most recent.

The command reports the packages containing cygwin1.dll available on the `www.cygwin.com` server in all versions. see `man cygcheck` for the `-p` option.

The same info is available at:

https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/cygwin/

If you want to look at all versions for all packages than you need to look directly at the setup.ini from one of the mirror:

http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/cygwin/x86_64/setup.ini

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but these commands are available **only** after Cygwin is already installed. In this case `uname -r` (from the answer linked in the question) is a much clearer way.

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to be _sure_ about the DLL version before installation (short of reading the machine code and finding some kind of reference on where Cygwin puts this information in the DLL) is to use the second and third methods (looking at the website). However, you'll either need to do so *right after* you download, or you'll need to check your download date at hope you can find somewhere where dates and files are listed (maybe the [Wayback Machine](archive.org), but I'm not sure. Hmm. talking about machine code made me wonder if one can use `objdump` ... Anyone know?