# Proper end pointer with strtol() and "0x"?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, strtol

```
strtol("0x", &endptr, 16);
```

This completes with `endptr` pointing to `"0x"`. I expected `"x"`. Is my C library's `strtol()` amiss, my expectations or something else?

The `"0x"` appears to be the beginning of an optional `"0x"` prefix, yet since it is not followed by a hex-digit, I would expect it to not qualify as a prefix and the parsed value should be from `"0"` with a non-numeric trailing `"x"`.  As is, `strtol()` implies *no conversion* since the end pointer points to the string beginning.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  char *endptr = "None";
  long val;

  errno = 0;
  val = strtol("0q", &endptr, 16);
  printf("val:%ld, errno:%d, endptr:<%s>\n", val, errno, endptr);

  errno = 0;
  val = strtol("0x", &endptr, 16);
  printf("val:%ld, errno:%d, endptr:<%s>\n", val, errno, endptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
val:0, errno:0, endptr:<q>
val:0, errno:0, endptr:<0x>  (Expected <x>)
```

C spec (emphasis mine):

> ... If the value of base is 16, the characters 0x or 0X may optionally precede the sequence of letters and digits, following the sign if present.   C17dr § 7.22.1.4 3
>
> The subject sequence is defined as the **longest** initial subsequence of the input string, starting with the first non-white-space character, that is **of the expected form**. The subject sequence contains no characters if the input string is empty or consists entirely of white space, or if the first non-whitespace character is other than a sign or a permissible letter or digit. C17dr § 7.22.1.4 4

Select build output info:

```
Invoking: Cygwin C Compiler
gcc -std=c11 -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c -fmessage-length=0 -v -MMD -MP -MF"Day1.d" -MT"Day1.d" -o "Day1.o" "../Day1.c"
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c11' '-O0' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wconversion' '-c' '-fmessage-length=0' '-v' '-MMD' '-MP' '-MF' 'Day1.d' '-MT' 'Day1.d' '-o' 'Day1.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/cc1.exe -quiet -v -MMD Day1.d -MF Day1.d -MP -MT Day1.d -dD -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../lib/../include/w32api -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/lib/../lib/../../include/w32api ../Day1.c -quiet -dumpbase Day1.c -dumpbase-ext .c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g3 -O0 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c11 -version -fmessage-length=0 -o /cygdrive/c/Users/TPC/AppData/Local/Temp/ccoGk5b2.s
GNU C11 (GCC) version 11.2.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
    compiled by GNU C version 11.2.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP
```

Comment: The "sequence of letters and digits" is empty – so the conversion is invalid.  It is reasonable to return the pointer to the `0` of `0x` because the input string was mal-formed.  You might get the pointer to the `x` if the base is `0` instead of `16`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Confident base 0 or base 16 makes no difference here.

Comment: MSVC gives the same result and their [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtol-wcstol-strtol-l-wcstol-l?view=msvc-170) says "If the first character is '0' and the second character is 'x' or 'X', the string is interpreted as a hexadecimal integer." Base 0 and 16 behave the same.

Comment: If it's any help, on macOS (Big Sur, 11.6.3), the program prints `val:0, errno:0, endptr:<q>` — `val:0, errno:0, endptr:<x>` as you expected.   And choosing the base 0 instead of 16 makes no difference. I think it is mildly ambiguous — neither is unequivocally wrong.

Comment: To be safe, you should set `errno = 0;` before each call to `strtol()`, though as `errno` is not set to a non-zero value, you're OK as it stands.  No function in the standard C library sets `errno` to zero; that is normally a behaviour copied by additional library functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK, `errno = 0` before both to set aside that concern.

Comment: I get the macOS behaviour on a Linux box too — RHEL 7.4 happens to be the machine I used (that is, the `endptr` points to `x`, not `0`, as you expected).

Comment: I get `endptr` pointing to `x` on CentOS Stream 8 (Glibc 2.28).  Although I agree that the spec could be read multiple ways here, it sounds like there is consistent behavior across a pretty good sampling of the widely used C implementations.  On what implementation does `endptr` get set to point to `0`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I like your idea of "neither is unequivocally wrong", yet the `"0x"` is an _optional_ prefix and the sequence is based on the _longest_ that fits the form.  `"0x"` does not fit the form: 0, x or X, _hex digits_, but does fit the form of _digit_. IAC, given competing choices, I’d expect the parsing to favor a successful conversion and not a failure.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Is your answer in the _Select build output info_ part of the post? _gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11_ ....  If not please advise how to determine.

Comment: Sorry, @chux-ReinstateMonica, I overlooked that bit.  It does leave me curious about which C library is being employed, however.  I don't see anything I recognize as a C standard library package on [Cygwin's package list](https://www.cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html) or on its [gcc package](https://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/gcc-core.html)'s dependency list.  I guess it may be using the MS C library, but the behavior you describe is inconsistent with the MS docs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Given [glibc not supported by Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25952829/2410359) and [get Cygwin DLL version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38675362/2410359) I think I am using cygwin-3.3.4-2 - a fairly recent version.

Comment: gcc Linux/glibc gives me `endptr:<x>` but my pretty old gcc Mingw64/MS CRT gives me `endptr:<0x>`. This appears to be a bug in the latter. I also found someone asking this very question back in 2016 - I believe the answer there is correct so I'll close this as a dupe. @chux-ReinstateMonica even commented on that answer back then :)

Comment: @Lundin I looked, yet did not find that old post.  Somehow it lurked in the back of my head that this was done before.  Thanks for for finding it.